# how to make bootable usb for dummies

Tags: boot, system-installation, usb

There are a lot of people telling how to make a bootable disc to other people who must understand a lot more than I do.  I try to read those answers and I say "OK, now tell me how to make bootable usb for dummies.  It would make Ubuntu much more popular if you did not need to be a computer hacker to figure out how to install it.  Why do you think Windows is popular?  You put in the disk and click install and 1 hour later you are surfing the web and emailing.  I need Ubuntu to be much easier to install than it is now!  Why not make a file to download that you copy to your USB then just reboot?  I would like to try an alternative to windows if someone could do a much simpler explanation to make a bootable USB, or even a bootable dvd.  Please help.  Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 4):

> It would make Ubuntu much more popular if you did not need to be a computer hacker to figure out how to install it.

You don't need to be a computer hacker to create bootable USB, regardless of which OS it is, Windows or Ubuntu or anything else. There's 3 key points you have to understand which are equally applicable anywhere:

1. You need iso file with OS installation
2. You need software to write that iso file to USB disk
3. You need to know how to boot from that USB.

[Official Ubuntu installation guide](https://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/create-a-usb-stick-on-windows) suggests using Ruffus. Other suggest using Unetbootin or [Universal USB installer](https://itsfoss.com/create-live-usb-of-ubuntu-in-windows/). Point is each USB creator has its own rules, so use the procedure they recommend.

> Why not make a file to download that you copy to your USB then just reboot?

Because OS iso files aren't like your pictures or mp3 files. They're sort of like zip files  and need to be uncompressed and written to USB sticks. Again, it doesn't matter if it's Windows or any other OS  - same principle applies.

If you don't want to deal with any of that, Ubuntu has its own shop with bootable USB drives on sale: https://shop.canonical.com/index.php?cPath=17

Please get out of the mindset that "everything is supposed to be simple". Computers are machines, and machines are meant to be operated. Please don't come to the community and show attitude, because that's exactly how your post sounds like.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to create in on Ubuntu then head here: https://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/create-a-usb-stick-on-ubuntu

It's with pictures as well.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to install Ubuntu is to use the [Linux Live USB Creator](http://www.linuxliveusb.com/) (a.k.a. LiLi). It's a simple, GUI based solution for anyone who wants to create a bootable linux USB or install linux from scratch. Hope this helps!

Comment: Can you please expand on this answer?  Perhaps provide a step by step explanation so that the OP can follow along?